# jupyter-lab gone from repos in 22.04?

Tags: apt, official-repositories, jupyter

Just upgraded from 21.04 to 22.04 LTS.
I don't exactly remember, how my jupyter services were installed previously, but I wanted to use system package manager `apt` to install `jupyter`.

While I see `jupyter` (notebook) and `jupyterhub` (I'd like to use that) in repositories, I can't find `jupyter-lab` anywhere.

Why is this the case? Was it always like this?
Should I necessarily go for `pip` or `conda` for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there never was a `jupyter-lab` package.

But there is a `python3-jupyterlab-server` I found it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=jupyterlab&searchon=names).
On `packages.ubuntu.com` which is the best website for Ubuntu package management ever!